# Showing a homomorphism of a field algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi : F\to F$ is a homomorphism. Prove $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Showing injectivity follows from the fact that the only ideals in a field are $(0)$ and $F$.  But how do you show surjectivity?

Comment: Of course $\mathbb{Q}$ may be replaced by an arbitrary ground field.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be an element of $F$.
Let $f(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.
Let $S$ be the set of all the roots of $f(X)$ in $F$.
$\varphi$ induces an injective map $S\to S$.
Since $S$ is a finite set, this map is surjective.
Hence $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: Why $\varphi$ induces an injective map $S \mapsto S$?

Answer (score 6):

The possible images of $\alpha \in F$ under $\varphi$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$ in $F$. This is a finite set $A$ because $\alpha$ is algebraic. Since $\varphi$ is injective and takes $A$ into $A$, it must be surjective on $A$. In particular, $\alpha$ is in the image of $\varphi$. Thus, $\varphi$ is surjective on $F$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\varphi$ isn't surjective, then since it's injective, it's isomorphic onto its image which must be a field.  So this would mean $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of $F$ onto a proper subfield of $F$, but this can't happen for dimension reasons.

EDIT: As Dylan pointed out, this doesn't work unless our extension is finite, so it's probably best to look at the other answers.

Comment: There is no assumption on the dimension though.

Comment: Are you assuming that $F$ is finite over $\mathbf Q$? In the general case the argument still boils down to dimension, but there is slightly more to say.

Comment: I am not assuming dimension is finite. What is the dimension argument? I don't see it.

Comment: @Galois I didn't claim that you were. The argument is something you know: if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field and $f\colon V \to V$ is an injective linear map, then $f$ is necessarily surjective.

Comment: You could push this through by taking $\alpha \in F$ and looking at the extension of $\mathbf Q$ generated by all the conjugates of $\alpha$ lying in $F$.