# In algebraic extension, field homomorphism induces isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I read [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152494/showing-a-homomorphism-of-a-field-algebraic-over-mathbbq-to-itself-is-an-is)'s first answer. But I'm curious about why $\varphi$ induces injective map $S \to S$. Isn't it possible to make $\varphi(\alpha)= k$ such that $k$ is not root of $f(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\varphi$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, hence

$$0 = \varphi(0) = \varphi(f(\alpha)) = \varphi\left(\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\alpha^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \varphi(c_k)\varphi(\alpha)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k\varphi(\alpha)^k = f(\varphi(\alpha)),$$

if $f(X) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n c_k X^k\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Thus $\varphi$ must map zeros of $f$ to zeros of $f$.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain last equality? Why $\varphi(f(\alpha)) = f(\varphi(\alpha))?$ Is the reason that it fixes its coefficient?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The coefficients of $f$ belong to the fixed field of $\varphi$, so $$\varphi\left(\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\alpha^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \varphi(c_k)\varphi(\alpha)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k\varphi(\alpha)^k.$$

Comment: Wow, thank you for kind explanation :)