# Why does surjective induced map imply surjective map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, field-theory

In the answer to this question: [Showing a homomorphism of a field algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself is an isomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152494/showing-a-homomorphism-of-a-field-algebraic-over-mathbbq-to-itself-is-an-is?rq=1) I am curious why the surjectivity of the induced map on the finite set implies that the map $\varphi$ is itself surjective. If you restrict the domain of a function, and that function is surjective, does this imply that the function itself is surjective? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is because every element in $F$ belongs to such a finite set, since $F$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbf Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a statement of linear algebra. Since the map is $\mathbb Q$ linear, it is a $\mathbb Q$ linear endomorphism, of a finite dimensional vector space. Apply rank nullity, and deduce that the kernel must be $0$ dimensional, so the image has full rank.

In the link you show, the proof is quite nice as well. Let $\alpha \in F$ be arbitrary. We wish to find some $\alpha^{\prime}$ so that $\phi(\alpha^{\prime})=\alpha$. Let $m_{\alpha}$ be the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, and $S$ all of its roots. Since $\phi:S \to S$ is a bijective map from roots of $m_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in F$, it follows that there exists some $\alpha^{\prime}$ that is a root of $m_\alpha$ so that $\phi(\alpha^{\prime})=\alpha$.

Comment: How do we know that $\phi$ is a bijective map of the roots of $m_{\alpha}$?

Comment: $\phi$ permutes roots of minimal polynomials, so the restriction is indeed a map $\phi:S \to S$. By assumption, this is injective.  Since $S$ is finite, every injection $S \to S$ is in fact bijective. The last statement has nothing to do with algebra, it's just counting and various proofs can be found on this website.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see why $\phi$ permutes the roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: if $p(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0=0$, then $\phi(p(x))=a_n(\phi(x)^n)+\dots a_0=\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: since it fixes $a_0, \dots a_n \in k$, or the ground field.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that $\varphi$ maps every element $\alpha \in F$ to some root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. So $\varphi$ permutes these roots. If you pick any element of $F$, it will be the image of some root of its minimal polynomial (otherwise the map induced on $S$ would not be surjective), so $\varphi$ is surjective.